# JPA CriteriaBuilder date operations

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa

I'm trying to translate my sql query to JPA Criteria Builder which is used in project which I'm working on and I stuck on date operation (PostgreSQL 9.3), I have a bit in where clause:

```
...AND cl.due_date + '3 YEARS' <= '2016-01-01 10:27:16.473' and cl.due_date + '3 YEARS' >= '2008-01-01 10:27:16.473'....
```

The problem is that I'm not able to create a Predicate object for "due_date" + "3 YEARS". 
Does anyone know how to manage to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to add (or subtract) the 3 years in Java, not in the query:

```
Calendar dueDateCalPlus3Years = Calendar.getInstance();
dueDateCalPlus3Years.set(set(year, month, date, hourOfDay, minute, second);
dueDateCalPlus3Years.add(Calendar.YEAR, -3);
Date dueDatePlus3Years = dueDateCalPlus3Years.getTime();

Expression<Date> cl;      // initialize it!
Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(cl, dueDatePlus3Years);
```

To be more concise, you can use the interval mapping [`CriteriaBuilder#between()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#between%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20Y,%20Y%29), and the query you have posted results in:

```
Date date1;
Date date2;

Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.not(criteriaBuilder.between(cl, date1, date2));
```

Comment: Ugh, that's ugly. There's no JPA Criteria mapping for `interval` literals? (Searches) ... looks like neither JPA Criteria nor JPQL do. Wow. That makes whole classes of query quite hard to write correctly, if it's possible at all.

Comment: @CraigRinger Yes, you can use an interval literal. See my update.

Comment: `BETWEEN` isn't an `INTERVAL`. It's an operator. `INTERVAL` lets you say things like `1 month 1 day`, working with dates as dates and intervals, not just counts of days or date literals.